# Why two session cookies

Tags: php, session-cookies

Why do I see two session cookies when php can have only one session at a time. I don't see second cookie on all requests but once it is created all data in cart is wiped out and I have to manually clear cookies. Anyone has an idea?

[image: Two Session cookies same name but different paths]

Comment: Looks like the cookie is set for different paths...!? I think we need more information to help you here.

Comment: Maybe expired one of both.

Comment: You can have same cookie names if you set different paths...

Answer (score 1):

A session cookie and a PHP session are different things.

A session cookie is a cookie which expires at the end of the current browser session.

A PHP session is a server side data storage area associated with a given user by some means (usually a session cookie).

You can have quite a lot of session cookies for a site. (For that matter, you can have multiple PHP sessions for a given user by changing the session cookie name).

Comment: so when we do session_start() a session cookie is created?

Answer (score 1):

You can set same cookie names when you there are different paths..
For example create at your localhost root folder lets say /var 
and put an index file as ...

```
<?php
// set the cookies
setcookie("test", "Emtpy path",0,'/');
setcookie("test", "Path var",0,'/var/');

?>
```

Then just see that there are 2 cookies with the same name but different paths..

Comment: I am working with an older version of oscommerce and according to my understanding session_start() creates that session cookie.